# Can we get Subscription id from Payment ID in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, payment, subscription

I want to know how to get the Subscription ID from Payment ID.
(I know how to cancel subscription by subscription id [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/tutorial))

When I created the subscription payment with test-account, I forgot to save the subscription id.

Now Facebook notify me about the subscription payment, but I can't cancel it.

Please help!!

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer from Facebook Team :)

First, I get the subscriptions of user by:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{user_id}}/payment.subscription?accesstoken={{apptoken}}
```

Then, I cancel subscription by:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{payment.subscriptions_id}}?status=canceled&accesstoken={{apptoken}}
```